# ServerSocket IP addr = ::/::

Tags: java, sockets, ip

While debugging my ServerSocket object, I got this expression `ServerSocket[addr=::/::,localport=32882]`. What does the `::/::` address mean please?

Comment: It's the IPv6 equivalent of the IPv4 Address 0.0.0.0 afaik

Comment: I assume it means it will listen on any IP address. You can make it that only a certain IP addresses is listened to.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It will listen on any IPv6 address in particular. Not sure if it uses the IPv4 stack at all then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

::(consecutive colons) is used when you have all zeros in the whole block.

Example:
2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334

Refer [Wikipedia for IPV6 Addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Addressing)

> One or more consecutive groups of zero value may be replaced with a
>   single empty group using two consecutive colons (::),[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Addressing) but the
>   substitution may only be applied once in the address, because multiple
>   occurrences would create an ambiguous representation.

The example address can be further simplified: 2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334

Considering your case, IP Address contains all zeros(i.e. 0.0.0.0)